# route is unable to run Controller

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to laravel... created a route and given its a controller which has a method to update a database.. but once it reads the route the app is unable to get to the controller

```
Route::post('/workorder/store/third/{$id}',
[
'uses'=>'WorkOrdersController@storeThird',
'as'=>'workorder.store.third'
]);
 //method in WorkOrderController
public function storeThird(Request $request,$id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'address_region'=>'required|string',
        'address_no'=>'required|string',
    ]);


    $workorder = WorkOrder::find($id);

    $workorder->address_region  = $request->address_region;
    $workorder->address_no  = $request->address_no;
    $workorder->save();

    return view('third-workorder',compact('workorder'));
}
```

results in browser ...
in the address bar.. "http://localhost:8000/workorder/store/third/9"
and in the browser .."Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

this.. view.blade looks like

```
<div class="modal" id="createThirdWorkshopModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('workorder.store.third',['id'=>$workorder->id]) }}" >
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigating directly to `http://localhost:8000/workorder/store/third/9` in your browser is a **`GET`** request, but you have the route defined as a route that handles a **`POST`** request. You need to submit something for that route to be "found":

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url("/workorder/store/third/".$id) }}" ...>
  ...
</form>
```

or define the route as

```
Route::any("/workorder/store/third/{$id}", ...);
```

to handle this.

Note: `::any()` handles all HTTP verbs (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.)

Comment: i have tried your solution but it did not work... Please i have updated the question with the routing in the view section (i used bootstrap modal) .. can you please check may be the problem is from that section

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::post('/workorder/store/third/{$id}', WorkOrdersController@storeThird)->name('workorder.store.third');
```

and use:

```
<a href="{{route('workorder.store.third', $id)}}">
...
</a>
```

Comment: i have tried your solution but it did not work... Please i have updated the question with the routing in the view section (i used bootstrap modal) .. can you please check may be the problem is from that section